# PHP sorting multidimensional array issue

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

this is how my array look likes:

```
array(2) {
  'yamaha' =>
  array(2) {
    'r1' =>
    array(3) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "2000"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "2001"
      [2] =>
      string(4) "1999"
    }
    'r2' =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "2000"
    }
  }
  'honda' =>
  array(3) {
    'ca-125' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "1996"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "1995"
    }
    'cb-1000-r' =>
    array(4) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "1993"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "1994"
      [2] =>
      string(4) "1995"
      [3] =>
      string(4) "1996"
    }
    'cb-1000-a' =>
    array(6) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "2008"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "2009"
      [2] =>
      string(4) "2010"
      [3] =>
      string(4) "2011"
      [4] =>
      string(4) "2012"
      [5] =>
      string(4) "2013"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to sort it after alphabetical order. If I do a `asort($myarray)`. It will sort after the first key. So I will get honda and yamaha. Which is correct, but I would like to also sort it after the type of the brand:  `cb-1000-r` and `cb-1000-a`(alphabetically) and the year in a descending order. Can someone help me with this ? Thank you

**[UPDATE]**
This is my json. you can use `json_decode`

```
 {"B":{"r2":["1999","2001","2000"],"r1":["2000"]},"A":{"A1":["1996","1995"],"A3":["1993","1994","1995","1996"],"A2":["2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013"]}}
```

and I would like to get this json:

```
 {"A":{"r1":["2000"],"r2":["2001","2000","1999"]},"B":{"A1":["1996","1995"],"A2":["2013","2012","2011","2010","2009","2008"],"A3":["1996","1995","1994","1993"]}}
```

Comment: @CBroe those examples are not with the level 2 or level 3 values . and not after the keys. For them the key is also a fixed one. But my key values are different for each level.

Comment: What would help us help you here is: 1) A sample array that we can copy and paste, i.e. as PHP source code, not as `var_dump` output. 2) A sample how you'd *like* your array to look afterwards instead of just a verbal explanation. 3) Preferably a summary of what you have tried and/or what you're stuck on exactly.

Comment: Hi @deceze I made an update to my post. I 've added 2 json.  How mine looks like and how i would like to have. json_decode can be used to get the php array. I also simplified the `keys`

Comment: You posted the same JSON twice…

Comment: @deceze srry, my bad. See my update again :) Also , also I can have more key values, like: `A4, A5, A6` etc. so my array is not a fixed one , as suggested in the suggested post (with possible answer), not sure if i made myself clear . Please let me know and many thnx helping me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through your nested arrays and sort each level of them:

```
$arr = json_decode('{"B":{"r2":["1999","2001","2000"],"r1":["2000"]},"A":{"A1":["1996","1995"],"A3":["1993","1994","1995","1996"],"A2":["2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013"]}}', true);

ksort($arr);

foreach ($arr as &$arr1) {
    ksort($arr1);
    
    foreach ($arr1 as &$arr2) {
        rsort($arr2);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Many thnx , it works. I guess the usage of & does the trick !